# Displaying table view cell subview on right in RTL

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view cell which displays a circle with checkmark and then text on the label besides it. All of this is done in the code without auto-layout. When I change the language to RTL, the label moves/displayed to right, but the custom circle/subview remains on the left.

***Code:***

```
override func formatCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.textLabel?.text = title
    cell.accessoryType = .none
    cell.accessoryView = nil
        
    renderCircle(cell)
}
    
private func renderCircle(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
    let circleDiameter = CGFloat(20)
        
    let y = (44.0 - circleDiameter) / 2.0        
    var circleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: y, width: circleDiameter, height: circleDiameter))
        
    if isPhoneRightToLeftLanguage() {
        let cellWidth = cell.frame.width - 16
        circleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: cellWidth, y: y, width: circleDiameter, height: circleDiameter))
    }
        
//        if isPhoneRightToLeftLanguage() {
//            circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
//        }
        
    drawCircle(into: circleView, diameter: circleDiameter)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(circleView)
        
    cell.indentationLevel = 1
    cell.indentationWidth = circleDiameter + 14
}
    
private func drawCircle(into view: UIView, diameter: CGFloat) {
    let circlePath = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: diameter, height: diameter), transform: nil)
        
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
    circleLayer.path = circlePath
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 1.3
    circleLayer.strokeColor = color
    circleLayer.fillColor = isActive ? color : UIColor.white.cgColor
    circleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        
    view.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        
    if isActive {
       let checkmarkPath = CGMutablePath()
       checkmarkPath.addLines(between: [
       CGPoint(x: 3.5, y: 10.5),
       CGPoint(x: 7.2, y: 14.2),
       CGPoint(x: 15.2, y: 6.2)
       ])
            
        let checkmarkLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        checkmarkLayer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
        checkmarkLayer.path = checkmarkPath
        checkmarkLayer.lineWidth = 1.3
        checkmarkLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        checkmarkLayer.fillColor = nil
            
        view.layer.addSublayer(checkmarkLayer)
    }
}
```

I tried adding this code which moves the circle to the right, but not after the label. It overrides the label.

```
if isPhoneRightToLeftLanguage() {
    let cellWidth = cell.frame.width - 16
    circleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: cellWidth, y: y, width: circleDiameter, height: circleDiameter))
}
```

When the device is in RTL, when you look at the table view cell from the right, it should display circle first and then label. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` and lay out its subview relatively to leading and trailing anchors (instead of using left and right related anchors) – this gives you desired behavior out-of-the-box.

Here's a Playground example:

```swift
import UIKit

final class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        backgroundColor = .green

        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red

        addSubview(view)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor),
                                     view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                                     view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3),
                                     view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)])
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

let cell = CustomCell()
cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 50.0)

UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
let rtlCell = CustomCell()
rtlCell.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 50.0)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: what is semanticContentAttribute?

Comment: "A semantic description of the view’s contents, used to determine whether the view should be flipped when switching between left-to-right and right-to-left layouts." (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622461-semanticcontentattribute) I just used it to force the cell to be displayed right-to-left in Playground, for demonstration purposes.